# Image Gallery – Click Button to Show Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m working on an Image Gallery with buttons to show images with an [X] in the upper right corner to close the image.  While the image is displayed the screen will not be darkened, but will be frozen from clicking anything except for the [X] to close the image.  In the attached code there’s a call to a CustomFunction, which is where I really need help.  All of the images will be smaller that 500 x 500 pixels and will be displayed in the center of the screen.  I’m hoping there’s a way to use Width and Height variables within the CustomFunction, so there’s only one function needed.
I appreciate help with this Image Gallery, and I hope the finished code will benefit others as well.  Thanks!

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Gallery</title>
</head>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" background="Background-Image.jpg" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div align="center">
  <center>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" width="1000">
    <tr><td width="1000" height="60" align="center" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="1000" align="center" colspan="3">
        <font face="Arial" color="#000000" size="7">Image Gallery</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td width="1000" height="60" align="center" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><!-- Image 1 -->
      <td width=100 height=50 align="center">&nbsp;
        <button onclick="CustomFunction()">Image 1</button>
      </td>
      <td width=900 height=50 align="left">
        <font face="Arial" color="#000000" style="font-size: 14pt">
        Image1_450Wx305H.jpg size in pixels is 450 Width x 305 Height.
        Click button to show image centered on the screen, then click X on image to close.
        </font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Area to show information about Image 1 -->
    <tr><td width="1000" height="330" align="center" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><!-- Image 2 -->
      <td width=100 height=50 align="center">&nbsp;
        <button onclick="CustomFunction()">Image 2</button>
      </td>
      <td width=900 height=50 align="left">
        <font face="Arial" color="#000000" style="font-size: 14pt">
        Image2_295Wx400H.png size in pixels is 295 Width x 400 Height.
        Click button to show image centered on the screen, then click X on image to close.
        </font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Area to show information about Image 2 -->
    <tr><td width="1000" height="330" align="center" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><!-- Image 3 -->
      <td width=100 height=50 align="center">&nbsp;
        <button onclick="CustomFunction()">Image 3</button>
      </td>
      <td width=900 height=50 align="left">
        <font face="Arial" color="#000000" style="font-size: 14pt">
        Image3_355Wx350H.gif size in pixels is 355 Width x 350 Height.
        Click button to show image centered on the screen, then click X on image to close.
        </font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Area to show information about Image 3 -->
    <tr><td width="1000" height="330" align="center" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </table>
  </center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<!-- Please note that spaces here are for visual only and are not the real code -->
```

Comment: Your code snippet does not have JS part.

Comment: Has nothing to do with your question but please: Don't use `align: center` or `<center>` or `align="left"` and stuff like this. Your code looks like it is from the last century. You should look into how to use semantic HTML and how to not use tables for layouts.

Comment: I am working from a HTML layout that a friend helped me with a while back. It’s out of date, but I was just hoping to figure out how to create a Javascript button function that will show an image and then close it. Thanks for your understanding.